# aws beanstalk config options for document root

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to predefine instance settings via config file but it just won't take it... if I create the environment it never reflects the settings.
I think I might just miss something obvious but can't find a solution. I probably terminated and created the env now 30 times with different config file names and different yaml syntax.

.elasticbeanstalk/production.config:

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini':
    option_name: document_root
    value: /htdocs
  - namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:asg':
    option_name: MinSize
    value: 2
  - namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:asg':
    option_name: MaxSize
    value: 8
  - namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment':
    option_name: env
    value: production
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That file belongs in the `.ebextensions` folder and not in `.elasticbeanstalk`

Comment: I must have read over this in all tutorials the whole time... thanks ;)